# Animation curve evaluate

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, curve, coroutine

I'm not sure how to assign speed to my Animation curve:

```
public float speed;
public AnimationCurve ac;

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos1, pos2, ac.Evaluate( ??? ));
```

I'm using it inside a coroutine.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
ac.Evaluate(deltaTime * speed);
```

According to [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html):

> public float Evaluate(float time);
>
> **Description**
>
> Evaluate the curve at time.
>
> **Parameter**
> time
>
> The time within the curve you want to evaluate (the horizontal axis in the curve graph).
>
> **Returns**
> float
>
> The value of the curve, at the point in time specified.

Comment: I think deltaTime is evaluated from `Time.time` minus starting time of the animation after animation is started